# Turn single fraction into multiple fraction expression

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I would like to find a way to take an algebraic fraction, where there is only a single numerator and denominator, and to turn it into multiple fractions multiplied by each other. I would like to control both the fractions that are formed, and the ordering of the fractions.

As an example, let's say I have two expressions:

```
F1 = b*c*d*e
F2 = b*f*g*h*i*k
```

I would like to divide one by the other, and have the result in terms of multiple fractions, with the fractions determined by my own rules. If I simply divide `F1` by `F2` in Mathematica, I obtain:

```
In= F1/F2 
Out= (c d e)/(f g h i k)
```

However, what if I wanted to always group `c / f` together such that I would get:

```
In=F1/F2
Out= (d e)/(g h i k)(c/f)
```

I have attempted to do this using `Rule`. For example,

```
In= {F1/F2} /. c/f -> (c/f)
```

but it still puts the `c/f` in the same fraction:

```
Out= {(c d e)/(f g h i k)}
```

Ideally, I would like to see

```
Out= (d e)/(g h i k)c/f
```

with the `c/f` as a separate fraction, at the end. Additionally, I would like to specify where the `c/f` lies compared to the `(d e)/(g h i k)`.

The motivation for this is that I have a large multiplication table of different expressions, which I will then paste into a LaTex table. I would like it to be ordered, and for certain expressions to be in fractions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
(F1/F2 /. c/f -> Defer[c/f]) /. aa_*bb_Defer -> Defer[aa]*bb

(* Out[15]= c/f (d e)/(g h i k) *)
```

Reordering will require a different operator e.g `NonCommutativeMultiply` on the rhs of the second replacement rule, and then some further formatting to make it look like ordinary multiplication.

--- edit ---

Except formatting `NonCommutativeMultiply` to look like ordinary multiplication seems to get one into a situation where the display is nice but it won't cut-and-paste the way it looks. Instead we can just use more `Defer` magic.

```
(F1/F2 /. c/f -> Defer[c/f]) /. aa_*bb_Defer -> Defer[Defer[aa]*bb]

(* Out[32]= (d e)/(g h i k) c/f *)
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: Could you provide a MWE for how to incorporate `NonCommutativeMultiply` into this?

Comment: The recursive `Defer` works really well! What if I want to have more than two multiplied fractions? I am finding that I cannot put multiple arguments in to get something like

`Out[]= ( e)/( h i k) c/f d/g`

I tried

`(F1/F2 /. c/f -> Defer[c/f] /. d/g -> Defer[d/g]) /. aa_*bb_Defer -> Defer[Defer[aa]*bb]`

and various other iterations, but to no avail.

Comment: Could you also clarify exactly how `Defer` is working here? This would be useful for applying this method further.

Comment: I don't actually know much regarding the "how", hence my allusion to magic. As best I understand, it is acting like `Hold` but less visibly in terms of display.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the family of Hold functions (it may be HoldForm) - - the nested Defer will allow cut-and-paste whereas the Hold functions usually keep everything intact.
Is the list exhaustive?  What are your criteria for "certain expressions to be in fractions"?  If the criteria is numeric, there are NHold functions...

Comment: HoldForm is certainly closer to what I need. The problem now is that the fractions are nested within the original numerator:
In[] =`(F1/F2 /. c/f -> Defer[c/f] /. d/g -> Defer[HoldForm[d/g]]) /. 
 aa_*bb_Defer -> HoldForm[Defer[aa]*bb]`
Out[] = `(e(c/f)/hik) (d/g)`.

Ideally, I would like to remove the c/f from the first numerator. Any ideas?

Comment: Earlier you mentioned "certain expressions to be in fractions" and "fractions determined by my own rules".  What are your criteria for this part of the desired calculation behavior?  If your desired table is definable beforehand, and / or we know the criteria for the variables to remain a fraction or not, then we might be able to normalize the numerator without getting multiples within the table.  Specifying c/f behavior explicitly is a better way instead of nested Defer and Hold families of functions (if possible).